# What is the concise form of physical constants? (What is the number in the parentheses?)

Tags: error-analysis, physical-constants, metrology

According to [nist](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mp) :

> **Proton mass $(m_p)$** :
>
> Numerical value $:  \mathrm{1.672 \ 621 \ 923 \ 69 \ × \ 10^{-27} \ kg}$
>
> Concise form  $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ :  \mathrm{1.672 \ 621 \ 923 \  69(51) \ × \ 10^{-27} kg}$

I want to store the constant of Proton Mass to use in calculation , but I'm confused which number to store : the $1.672 \ 621 \ 923 \ 69 \ × \ 10^{-27}$ or the $1.672 \ 621 \ 923 \ 69(51) \ × \ 10^{-27}$?

So what is Concise form? and what is the number inside the parentheses (e.g $51$), is it just 2 more number of the constant for more precision? I couldn't find the explanation anywhere else.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/563879/123208

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers inside the parentheses represent the *uncertainty*.

If you wanted to explicitly include the uncertainty in the proton's mass, you would write it as $$m_p=(1.672\ 621\ 923\ 69  \pm 0.000\ 000\ 000\ 51) \times 10^{-27}\text{kg}$$ Or in "*concise form*" $$m_p=1.672\ 621\ 923\ 69(51)\times 10^{-27}\text{kg}$$

Unless the problem(s) you are solving state that you must include uncertainties,  you would use $$m_p=1.672\ 621\ 923\ 69 \times 10^{-27}\text{kg}$$ for the mass in your calculations.

Answer (score 4):

It's the "concise form" for writing uncertainties. I.e. $1.672\, 621\, 923\, 69(51)\times 10^{-27}$ kg instead of $(1.672\, 621\, 923\, 69\pm0.000\, 000\, 000\, 51)\times 10^{-27}$ kg.